# Should this question have really been closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I really don't think that my question:

[Does Scala have static imports like Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14195231/1061426)

is in any way a candidate for closure. It asks a question. There have been answers. The answers answer the question, and have received upvotes. In fact, the question itself has received numerous up and down votes.

I think there's an air of unfortunate intellectual arrogance here - "oooh, a simple question! i only want stackoverflow questions to be about logic branching and obscure yet technically fun questions"

I'm arguing that as much as the question is simple, it also isn't (at the time of writing) particularly google-able nor obvious to anybody new to scala.
But if it *must* be closed, it shouldn't be closed under "not constructive" - maybe invent a new tag "intellectually inferior" or something?

Comment: Related: [How should I treat a question which the asker just should have tried?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124161/1358870), [Introduce a “general reference” close reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86043/135887) (status-declined), etc.  It should not have been closed as Not Constructive (it's NARQ or Too Localized maybe, if the Scala folks close RTFM questions as Too Localized), but it should have been downvoted into oblivion for not bothering with research before asking.

Comment: I almost quit SO a long time ago because of the onslaught of, frankly, stupid beginner questions of people that just need to read their books and try things out. The questioner even says he put no time into it and has not read anything. We are not his search engine.

Comment: @GManNickG you are. If you're participating on this site - which is a search engine of knowledge - then you are "my" search engine. It is voluntary of course. But if OTHER PEOPLE are willing to provide the answer, and OTHER PEOPLE think the question is valuable, what is the point of closing it?

Comment: @GManNickG It takes multiple votes to close a question so obviously enough people don't think it is valuable.

Comment: The real crime here is the fact that you chose the answer with 0 votes vs. the much more complete answer with 9 votes.

Comment: @AustinHenley: I don't think we disagree.

Comment: @AndyDwyer no real crime - it was the first answer, it answered the question completely. The fuller answer is better, and still there, and i like it a lot. But the answer i selected in completely correct.

Comment: @GManNickG there really isn't any wordplay - clever or not - on my part here.

Comment: @bharal - [Voting is different on Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences). So don't take it personally.

Comment: «But downvoting the brother who took the time to provide a correct, succinct answer? Why?» Because it's a crappy answer. It's one tiny notch above the absolute rock-bottom minimum for an answer to that question.

Comment: @hims056 I'm not referring to the meta, i'm referring to the SO voting.

Comment: @JoshCaswell the question is simple - and look, i like the more popular answer too, but the answer currently *completely* answers the question, and does it succinctly. There is no reason to downvote it.

Comment: It's _always_ possible to add some relevant detail, explanation, background, links, doc quotes, no matter how simple the question.

Comment: @JoshCaswell  Yes, it is. That still doesn't make the answer given a poor one. It is correct. I'm not asking for extra information - the answer shows a grasp of the problem, and a solution. 
I'm arguing that you should only downvote an answer that is *wrong* or *misleading*, not because the answerer missed an opportunity to expand on a concept.

Answer (score 14):

The question should probably be closed as "too localized -- unlikely to be helpful to any future readers". Why?

If you had, in the ten minutes that you've been learning Scala, done a [Google search for "scala static import"](http://www.google.com/search?ie=utf8&oe=utf8&q=scala+static+import&nfpr=1) you would have found at least half a dozen links that gave you the answer, and probably some background info. I think it's reasonable to assume that *anyone* else with this question will put more effort into it than you, and thus find the answer on her own.

Your question is also constructed in such a way that that you have attracted, and accepted, an answer that consists essentially of "Yes." You haven't really tried anything, you haven't looked into the problem at all, and you haven't included the results of any research.*

All of these things increase the chances that your question will elicit a modicum of depth from an answer. Absent them, your question is essentially a shout over the cubicle wall to bother your teammate, who grunts in reply. The kind of answer you've gotten doesn't provide much value to anyone else; the problems with it, and with your question, are quite similar to the [problems with subjective questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

Further, are *you* ever going to need to look at this question again? Why does it even need to be open? Apparently "Yes" was all you needed to know.

This may seem like elitism, but the homework and depth requirements are very important indicators for a question's long-term usefulness and suitability for the archive of solutions to programming questions that Stack Overflow aims at being.

---

*You haven't so much as included *the error you say you're getting*, which is a pretty basic thing to do when asking for technical help. It would also increase the question's search target usefulness.

Comment: Heh... Was just about to answer with the "next time, take 2 seconds and copy the error" remark; that's really pretty damning, since even if lots of other people *do* encounter the *exact* same problem, a sloppy description won't help them find it.

Answer (score 11):

You should invest more than 10 minutes into a problem before asking us. Because then you are costing several people their own time just because you haven't thoroughly checked some sort of reference.

I think it was closed for good reason.

**EDIT:** If you google "scala static import" and click the first link, you have an answer.

Comment: What time am i actually costing someone? They're *on* the site, so they're obviously not hard at work stopping their nuclear reactor from imploding.
The time to read? It shouldn't take longer than a handful of seconds to read my question. 
The time to answer? If you don't want to answer, don't.

If it takes me 10 minutes to find a solution, its going to take Bob and Jane 10 minutes too. 
If it takes you 5 seconds to answer, you've saved humanity some 30 minutes - i'll buy a few reasons for why the question should be closed, but "the time cost" is not one of them

Comment: @bharal It is our time. You aren't in a position to tell us how much it is worth. Especially if multiple people are in the middle of answering it.

Comment: I don't want to jump into a giant argument of time (you're wrong, everybody's time is worth the same - because it is invaluable). I don't get your "multiple people are answering it" bit - what are you trying to say

Comment: @bharal I am saying if multiple people are wasting their time then it quickly adds up. If everyones time is invaluable then treat it as such and put more effort into solving your problems instead of expecting us to do it for you.

Comment: You're right - but the initial cost of reading the question - especially this question, which should take an intermediate english reader no longer than half a minute to read, and a fluent one a matter of seconds - is incredibly low.
The cost of *finding* the answer, however, over and over again - ESPECIALLY AS THE QUESTION ISN'T GOOGLE-READY - is *very* high.

Ergo the overall value to, um, the "global pool of time" in general, and to this site specifically, then, is large.

Comment: There is no harm in asking simple questions.  There is harm in not having bothered performing research first.  The question wasn't closed because it was too simple, it was closed because it's an RTFM question and you didn't even bother Ring TFM.

Comment: @bharal: I don't know where you get the idea that your question isn't Googleable. It took me ten seconds to find the answer -- [search](http://www.google.com/search?q=scala+static+import), [click first link](https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/scala_for_java_programmers_part), find-in-page "static import".

Comment: @bharal The more important piece here for the site and the community is that if a lot of low-quality and/or no-effort questions flood the site, the really smart people who can answer the really hard questions will get turned off.  There are probably a couple dozen people who answer questions here who are irreplaceable and at the top of their respective fields.  They come here because the quality of questions is better, and if we let this turn into Yahoo Answers then they will not stay long.